# Forth editor/customizable editor

Tags: macos, colors, editor, forth

I'm looking for an OS X editor (preferably a dedicated Forth editor, but I doubt it exists) that has/can be customized to change the font color of Forth variables, programs, etc. If not, is there any sort of workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but: atom with the forth-language package. See http://atom.io/

Longer answer:

I have tried both emacs and atom on Mac OS X and both are more than adequate for editing Forth. Atom is lighter and easier to learn while maintaining many emacs-ish capabilities (cmd-shift-p in place of meta-x).

I don't have automatic indenting working in atom yet, the syntax package I found needs a little work, but this hasn't been a real problem as yet.

atom also plays well with git.

I'm using the following packages: emacs-plus, language-forth, clipboard-plus, disable-arrow-keys. The key and clipboard are for a more emacs like experience. There are more themes and color schemes than I need available, I'm using the 4-color-dark and minimal-syntax themes.

Answer (score 1):

[UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/uex.html) has a Forth syntax highlight mode.  MicroProcessor Engineering have an up to date copy in there [downloads](http://www.mpeforth.com/arena.htm) page.

Answer (score 1):

Look no further !!

I'm currently programming in FORTH using the 'Visual Studio Code; editor.
Has (installable) syntax-highlighting for many languages, including FORTH.

Have a try:
https://code.visualstudio.com/download

It has even automatic indenting, AND code folding!!

...and let me know if you like it like I do.

Robbert / PA3BKL

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Gedit and if you change the forth.lang in the app you can change the syntax highlighting